# yes command replacement unix shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, script

Is there any command like `yes` command for Sun OS 5.8?

I want to give to write a script which I need to press `n` continuously, which I want to automate.

I tried with `yes` command but it is not there in Sun OS 5.8 So can someone give me suggestion?

```
{ echo 4 ; yes n ; } | script name
```

Need to press 4 when script start runs and then need to press `n` almost 30 times whenever script stops.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have Sun OS or anything like that, but I imagine you can achieve something similar with a command like

> { echo 4; while [ 1 ]; do echo n; done; } | script_name

This will echo 4, then repeatedly n  - which appears to be the behaviour you are seeking.